# Jsoup selectors returning all values instead of searched values

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm learning how to use jsoup and I've created a method called `search` which uses jsoup's selectors `contains`and `containsOwn` to search for a given item and return it's price. (For now the item name is hardcoded for testing purposes but the method will later take in a parameter to accept any item name).

The problem I'm having is that the selector isn't working and all the prices on the page are being returned instead of the one item being searched for, in this case "blinds". So in this example if you follow the link, only one item on that page says blinds and the price is listed as "$30 - $110 original $18 - $66 sale" but every item on that page gets returned instead.

I am aware that with jsoup I can explicitly call the name of the div and just extract the information from it that way. But I wanted to turn this into a bigger project and also extract prices from the same item from other chains such as Walmart, Sears, Macy's etc. Not just that particular website I used in my code. So I can't explicitly call the div name if I wanted to do that because that would only solve the problem for one site, but not the others and I wanted to take on an approach that encompasses the majority of those sites all at once.

How do I extract the price associated with its rightful item? Is there any way of doing it so that the item and price extracting will apply to most websites?

I would appreciate any help.

```
private static String search(){
    Document doc;
    String priceText = null;

    try{
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.jcpenney.com/for-the-home/sale/cat.jump?id=cat100590341&deptId=dept20000011").get();
        Elements divs = doc.select("div");
        HashMap items = new HashMap();
        for(Element element : doc.select("div:contains(blinds)")){

            //For those items that say "buy 1 get 1 free"
            String buyOneText = divs.select(":containsOwn(buy 1)").text();
            Element all = divs.select(":containsOwn($)").first();
            priceText = element.select(":containsOwn($)").text();
            items.put(element, priceText);
        }
        System.out.println(priceText);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return priceText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have tried at least to debug your app, then for sure, you will spot where is your mistake.
Put breakpoint for example on this line:

```
String buyOneText = divs.select(":containsOwn(buy 1)").text();
```

and then you will see, that really this element in loop contains blinds text. (and as all, that were selected)

I don't know why to make super universal tools, that will be working everywhere - IMO is not possible, and for every page you have to make your own crawler. In this case probably your code should be looking like this (I have to added timeout + this code is not working fully on my side, as I have default currency PLN):

```
private static String search() {
        Document doc;
        String priceText = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.jcpenney.com/for-the-home/sale/cat.jump?id=cat100590341&deptId=dept20000011").timeout(10000).get();
            Elements divs = doc.select("div[class=price_description]");
            HashMap items = new HashMap();
            for (Element element : divs.select("div:contains(blinds)")) {

                //For those items that say "buy 1 get 1 free"
                String buyOneText = divs.select(":containsOwn(buy 1)").text();
                Element all = divs.select(":containsOwn($)").first();
                priceText = element.select(":containsOwn($)").text();
                items.put(element, priceText);
            }
            System.out.println(priceText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return priceText;
    }
```